# MySQL regexp returns wrong result when working with repeated character

Tags: mysql, regex

With MySQL 5.7, I have the following query:

```sql
SELECT `slug` FROM `unittest`.`test_item`
WHERE `slug` REGEXP '^some-slug[0-9]*$'
ORDER BY `slug` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

That works just fine for the items with the slugs `some-slug1` to `some-slug9`, but once I have a slug like `some-slug10`, that one won't be found. Instead, the result is `some-slug9` all the time.
I've set up an example at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/uNPt5j/1), where it's seems to work.

What am I missing here regarding MySQL?

Comment: It seems to work just fine when I test it: https://dbfiddle.uk/aHuXWht9 . Are you sure there isn't something else going on there?

Comment: You have `LIMIT 1` so it only returns the first result. If you return all the results you'll see `some-slug10` in it.

Comment: It is because you are ordering by `slug DESC` and `some-slug9` is > `some-slug10`. You could just `ORDER BY slug + 0 DESC`

Comment: Since it's a string, it's doing lexicographic sorting, not numeric, so `9 > 10`

Comment: @user1191247 That won't work, since the number isn't at the beginning of `slug`.

Comment: Anyway, I'ld gladly accept an answer of one of you guys. :)

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. I was being dumb. Could ``ORDER BY SUBSTRING(`slug`, 10) + 0 DESC``

Comment: @user1191247 Nice, works like a charm - would you provide an answer?

Comment: @user1191247 Well, the `+0` part is something special, I think. To be honest, I don't even understand exactly what it does. Converting the substring to a number, so the sorting changes? Ofc. I can delete the question if that helps keeping things clear here ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your query to:

```
SELECT `slug`
FROM `unittest`.`test_item`
WHERE `slug` REGEXP '^some-slug[0-9]*$'
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(`slug`, 10) + 0 DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

[`` SUBSTRING(`slug`, 10) ``](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) (`10` being the position of the first digit) will return numeric component as a string and then `+0` causes an implicit conversion to a numeric value (DOUBLE according to Workbench).

You could also:

```
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(`slug`, 10) AS UNSIGNED) DESC
```

to explicitly [`CAST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) the numeric component to an `UNSIGNED BIGINT`.

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DCPHHrC0).

P.S. Interestingly, for this simple case, `SUBSTRING()` is an order of magnitude faster than `REGEXP_REPLACE()`. This is unlikely to be significant in this case, but worth bearing in mind as a general rule. If you have a very simple scenario that can be easily solved with simple string functions, they are much faster than invoking regex.

Comment: Thanks again for your help! You could probably add an explanation for the `10` in there. (Just for the sake of completeness, I understand it's the position right after the 9 character word `"some-slug"`.)

Comment: Added brief explanation ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
SELECT 
  `slug`,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(`slug`,'[a-z]','')
FROM `test_item`
WHERE `slug` REGEXP '^some-slug[0-9]*$'
ORDER BY CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(`slug`,'[a-z]','') as SIGNED)
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/US5wf9Bk)

EDIT: As a bonus (just to learn)

Why is this also order correctly?

```
SELECT 
  `slug`,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(`slug`,'[a-z]','')
FROM `test_item`
WHERE `slug` REGEXP '^some-slug[0-9]*$'
ORDER BY CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(`slug`,'[a-z]','') as UNSIGNED)
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/i6cMQh4j)

HINT: Just add `CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(`slug`,'[a-z]','') as UNSIGNED)` to your select, and you will see why.